# CakePHP 3 and partial View update via Ajax - How it should be done?

Tags: ajax, cakephp-3.0, partials

One more time I have bumped into the problem how partial view upadtes via ajax should be done in CakePHP3.
From my point of view, there are 3 ways of doing this:

1. Render required part of the view in dedicated controller action and simply inject the HTML.
2. Create dedicated template (*.ctp) file for every ajax action, render it like any other action but without the main layout and inject the HTML (kind of variant 1 but with separated VC logic).
3. Return only required data as an ajax response (eg. entity data) and build part of my view from javascript on client side.

I think that the most efficient solution will be variant 2 because of separation of controller and view logic.
Variant 1 would most probably cause view beeing built twice (on demand, and after request is processed) like in following snipped:

```
public function ajaxRenderAuditDetails($id = null)
{
    if ($id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if ($this->request->is("ajax")) {
        $this->set("result", $this->viewBuilder()->build()->cell("audits", [$id]));
    }
}
```

Variant 3 on the other hand will double the view code in some cases - for example the same html will be genrated in ViewCell as well as on client side javascript
What are the best practices for handling such functionality?

Comment: To eliminate duplication like this, I've often created an element that both the main view and the Ajax view call. The Ajax view is very often nothing but echoing the output of the element.

Comment: @GregSchmidt so I assume that dedicated controller action is the way to go in your opinnion ??

Comment: Depends on the situation... For example, if I have a "view X" page that has multiple related Y records, the Templates/X/view.ctp might output each Y with an element, and the same element could be used by an Ajax call to add a Y to this X. Not sure if that answers your question. On re-reading, I don't think that this quite matches any of your three options, but it's closest to #2.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Sounds like #2. I went that way in current project and it is not that bad besides boilerplate action code. Thank you for your opinion.