# CakePHP 3 and partial View update via Ajax - How it should be implemented?

Tags: ajax, partials, cakephp-3.x

I want to render a cakephp3 template by ajax and inject the html into a loaded page (without reloading the page).

According to 
[CakePHP 3 and partial View update via Ajax - How it should be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697753/cakephp-3-and-partial-view-update-via-ajax-how-it-should-be-done),
the idea can be

> Create dedicated template (*.ctp) file for every ajax action, render
>   it like any other action but without the main layout and inject the
>   HTML (kind of variant 1 but with separated VC logic).

It also provides a partial example code:

```
public function ajaxRenderAuditDetails($id = null)
{
    if ($id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if ($this->request->is("ajax")) {
        $this->set("result", $this->viewBuilder()->build()->cell("audits", [$id]));
    }
}
```

May anyone suggest a full example?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use a Ajax call for get data from server. In term of CakePhp you will call a controller function using Ajax. This function call a ctp file which render your partial view. Success function of Ajax should updated or append the partial view. A complete example code for this process is here -

Ajax code for call controller function -

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: basepath/controllername/controllerfunction, 
            type: "POST", 
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $(selector).html(data);
            }
        });

   public function ajaxRenderAuditDetails($id = null){
      $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
      if ($id == null) {
        return null;
      }
      if ($this->request->is("ajax")) {
        $this->set("result", $this->viewBuilder()->build()->cell("audits", [$id]));
     }
  }
```

Put your required html or logics in ctp file.

This is not a running code. It is sample example for updating partial view in CakePhp.